# Правильно разделить пространство ip адресов

Tags: ip, подсети

Провайдеру Internet принадлежит адресное пространство `200.25.0.0/16`.
Для выдачи адресов клиентам провайдер использует часть своих адресов `200.25.0.0/20`.

Используя префиксную технологию `CIDR` разделить данное адресное пространство на 4 части (4 организации):

1. Организация A - половина адресов.
2. Организация B - 1/4 часть адресов.
3. Организации C и D - по 1/8 части адресов.

Comment: Прямая трансляция с экзамена?

Comment: Нет. Это дз. Не могу понять условие.

Comment: Чего тут понимать? подели 200,25,0,0/20 на 4 подсети: 21, 22 и две по 23.

Comment: Ну вы хоть бы не поленились переформулировать вообще д/з так, чтобы в нём на было императива («разделить»).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сеть `200.25.0.0/20` означает наличие `32-20=12` бит на адрес.
Соответственно, все адреса сети: `200.25.0-15.0-255`

Отберём 1/2 для A: `0-7.0-255`
Отберём 1/4 для B: `8-11.0-255`
Отберём 1/8 для C: `12-13.0-255`
Отберём 1/8 для D: `14-15.0-255`

В битовом представлении это будет выглядеть как:

```
  ....|........  
A 0***|******** - 0.0/21
B 10**|******** - 8.0/22
C 110*|******** - 12.0/23
D 111*|******** - 14.0/23
```